# ValueError raises even when code has given values

Tags: python, list, valueerror

I am trying to work on a piece of code that helps me remove all conjunctions pronouns, punctuation, etc.

```
macbeth = open("macbeth.txt", "r")

contents = macbeth.read()

contents = contents.split()  

def remove_uninteresting_stuff(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

    for x in punctuations:
        file_contents.remove(x)
        
        
    for x in uninteresting_words:
        file_contents.remove(x)

    return file_contents

print(remove_uninteresting_stuff(contents))
```

This code raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testingFile.py", line 33, in <module>
    print(remove_uninteresting_stuff(contents))
  File "testingFile.py", line 25, in remove_uninteresting_stuff
    file_contents.remove(x)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Now obviously, in a novel such as Macbeth(by Shakespear), these words will exist.

Can someone explain this error and help me fix this?

Comment: What word is failing? `print(x)` before the failing line.

Comment: Or maybe you don't care that the text doesn't contain a particular word, and just surround the `file_content.remove` with a `try/except` block.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that your list of words and punctuations all exist in Macbeth when in fact that is not the case.

A different way to write this that might work is something like:

```
macbeth = open("macbeth.txt", "r")

contents = macbeth.read()

contents = contents.split()  

def remove_uninteresting_stuff(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

    file_contents = [word for word in file_contents if word not in uninteresting_words and word not in punctuations]

    return file_contents

print(remove_uninteresting_stuff(contents))
```

The difference is that here you're checking if the word does not exist in your list of unwanted words versus removing the unwanted words from your contents regardless if it exists or not.

Since you cannot be sure that your unwanted word exists in your contents, you'll have to check if it exists first then remove it which is the same as only keeping in the words that do not exist in your unwanted words list (as I've done in the code snippet).

**Update**

The code snippet above would not work if the punctuations you want to remove are part of a word (surprise!)

This on the other hand does work:

```
contents = "The the a to To IF is OF and and or here when where where how all ANY any both few whom who wHo!! -;."

contents = contents.split()  

def remove_uninteresting_stuff(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

    file_contents = [word.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuations)) for word in file_contents]
    file_contents = [word for word in file_contents if word.lower() not in uninteresting_words]

    return file_contents

print(remove_uninteresting_stuff(contents))
```

Comment: Does not work how? It's not removing all the unwanted words? If that's the case, you probably want to normalize your contents first which in this case should be making all the words lowercase before checking.

Comment: well didnt work either, i think the problem is that its only removing one of each type of unwanted word, and not every unwanted word there is.

Comment: Check answer update, the output was an empty list which indicates it removed all unwanted words.

Comment: doesn't work either, try download Macbeth from websites such as projectgutenburg.org and run it using your code, absolutely doesn't work.

Comment: I did and it did work. Can you try updating your question with a snippet of Macbeth that is not being filtered out when running my snippet?

Comment: well the thing is i am working on a wordcloud and nothing has worked so far. I will try your solution as given above.

Comment: here's a word cloud generated using my snippet:
https://imgur.com/a/XrCv2iL ran on Macbeth downloaded from: https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2264